# copy function not copy one2many relation field(odoo 10)

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10, odoo

I want to copy all the information stored in the one2many relation when I double the entry to the view. All values except for the on2many relation are copied. I have even tried to overwrite the copy function to do it by hand but there is something I must be doing wrong or that I have not come to understand.

Here its the code of the class

```py
 class EmpleadosProductos(models.Model):
    _name = "employee.as.product"

    collection_lines = {}
    employee_line = fields.One2many(
        'employee.line', 
        'order_id', 
        string='Employee Lines'
        )

    state = fields.Selection([('creado', 'Creado'),
        ('confirmado', 'Confirmado'),
        ('cancelado', 'Cancelado'),
        ('validado', 'Validado'),
        ('pagado', 'Pagado')
        ], string='Status', index=True, readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange', copy=False, default='creado', required=True, help='Estado del parte de empleado')

    companyias = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Obra', domain=[('is_company', '=', True)])
    amount_total = fields.Monetary(string='Total', store=True, readonly=True, compute='_calcularTotal')
    journal_entry = fields.Many2one('account.move')


    currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency', required=True, default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.currency_id.id)
    fecha = fields.Date('Fecha')
    referencia = fields.Char(string='Ref', required=True) 
    # referencia = fields.Char(string='Ref', required=True) 
    journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', 'Journal')

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('refererecia_constraint', 'unique(referencia)', 'La referencia debe de ser única!'),
    ]

    @api.multi
    def action_confirmar(self):
        self.write({'state': 'confirmado'})

    @api.multi
    def action_cancelar(self):
        self.write({'state': 'cancelado'})

    @api.multi
    def action_validar(self):
        self.write({'state': 'validado'})

    @api.multi
    def action_pagar(self):
        self.write({'state': 'pagado'})

    @api.multi
    def copy(self, default):
        _logger.info("DEBBUG:" + " default " +  str(default))
        _logger.info("DEBBUG:" + " self.employee_line " +  str(self.employee_line.name_get()))
        for line in self.employee_line:
            _logger.info("DEBBUG:" + " self.employee_line " +  str(line.name_get()))
        default = dict(default or {})
        default.update({
            'employee_line' : self.employee_line,
            'referencia': '',
        })
        # _logger.info("DEBBUG:" + str(vals))
        return super(EmpleadosProductos, self).copy(default)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `copy=True` to `employee_line` definition:

```
class EmpleadosProductos(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.as.product'

    employee_line = fields.One2many(
        'employee.line',
        'order_id',
        string='Employee Lines',
        copy=True,
    )
```

After you do that, you should not need to extend/override the `copy()` method.

Comment: ops i dont see the last part when i comment copy, it works. Thx :)